# Javascript How to find a complete class object in an array

Tags: javascript, angular

I have an array of objects that I use for a materials table datasource. I need to see if this row already exists in the datasource array before adding it.

There is no key value in this array. So I need to check if all items are unique

```
var datasource = [
     { Name: Jon,  Address: 123 something }, {Name: Tyler , Address: 333 Something}

]

var rowtoAdd = [
     { Name: Jon,  Address: 123 something }

]

const found = datasource.find(x => x.name == rowtoAdd.Name && x.Address == rowtoAdd.Address)
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: the rowtoAdd will be array or an object?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Object comparison in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068834/object-comparison-in-javascript)

Comment: @Shubham rowtoAdd will be pushed into the datasource array ONLY if it doesnt already exist. In my scenario it would already exist but I need a way to check if it does

Comment: @zmag It is similar if it were a 1:1 object array. but I need a 1:many comparison

Answer (score 0):

One way you can do this is by hashing the elements. Your current solution takes O(n) time each time you need to check. if you create a hashtable it will take 0(n) to create the table but the run time will O(1) for all consecutive run.

```
var datasource = [
     { "Name": "Jon",  "Address": "123 something" }, {"Name": "Tyler" , "Address": "333 Something"}

]

var map = datasource.reduce(function(map, obj) {
    map[obj.Name+obj.Address] = true;
    return map;
}, {});

rowtoAdd = { "Name": "Jon",  "Address": "123 something" }
if(!map[rowtoAdd.Name+rowtoAdd.Address])
datasource.push(rowtoAdd)
```

So, in sort reduce your array to a hashmap